# How to update TabLayout when returning from an activity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-tablayout

My app I am working on has 3 tabs in TabLayout. Each is comprised of a listview. Additionally I am using a FragmentStatePageAdapter and a custom adapter. When you click on an item in the ListView it launches an activity. After you have completed a task in the activity it updates some global array data. Next the user could hit the back button on their phone to return. This is where the issue resides.

Now Tab1 never changes, I later wish to implement that returning sets it to Tab1. That's a later worry. The problem is that the middle tab does not reload. I understand the reason is because the middle tab is already created so visually the swipe effect looks accurate. Tab3 will update if coming from Tab1 because it was not loaded yet.

I have tried various listeners, working with onResume in the tablayout Fragment. I do not have notifydatasetchanged anywhere in my code and haven't been able to implement that. I presume I have somehow implemented something wrong and overpassed the correct solution being I have tried so many things.

Here is some code to help understand how I have everything setup.

---

**MainActivity**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);

    //more

    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    tabLayout.setScrollPosition(0, 0f, true);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**SectionsPagerAdapter**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
protected Context mContext;

public SectionsPagerAdapter( FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
    int number = position;
    switch (number) {
        case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
            return TabFragment1.newInstance();
        case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
            return TabFragment2.newInstance();
        case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
            return TabFragment3.newInstance();
        default:
            return null;
    }

    // return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return 3;
}


@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "All";
        case 1:
            return "Unfinished";
        case 2:
            return "Completed";
    }
    return null;
}}
```

**MyAdapter**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
protected Context mContext;

public SectionsPagerAdapter( FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
    int number = position;
    switch (number) {
        case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
            return TabFragment1.newInstance();
        case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
            return TabFragment2.newInstance();
        case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
            return TabFragment3.newInstance();
        default:
            return null;
    }

    // return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return 3;
}


@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "All";
        case 1:
            return "Unfinished";
        case 2:
            return "Completed";
    }
    return null;
}}
```

**Fragment1** (all three fragments are the exact same)

```
public class TabFragment1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

public ArrayList<String> mylist1 = new ArrayList<>();

// newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
public static TabFragment1 newInstance() {
    TabFragment1 fragmentFirst = new TabFragment1();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    //pass a list or something?
    fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentFirst;
}

// Store instance variables based on arguments passed
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

// Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    mylist1.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayInt.length; i++) {

            mylist1.add(array[i]);

    }


    final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_label);

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), mylist1);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Click on Item
    //selecting items
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //goes to new activity passing the item name
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MapsActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            //get text for current item
            //String textGet = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            String textGet = mylist1.get(position);
            //put text into a bundle and add to intent
            intent.putExtra("text", textGet);

            //get position to carry integer
            intent.putExtra("position", position);

            intent.putExtras(b);

            //begin other activity
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Here is an older attempt at notifying data set changed but no luck. I put this in the fragment itself.

```
 public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

  Log.e("Frag2", "Refresh Test");

    // a check so it doesnt run first time starting app and crashing
    if (g != 0) {
        updateData();
    }
    g = 1;

}

private void updateData(){
    Log.e("Frag2", "Refresh Test");
    this.mylist2.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayInt.length; i++) {
        if (arrayInt[i] == 1) {
            this.mylist2.add(array[i]);
        }
    }

    adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), this.mylist2);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: My solution to this came to when I was reading best practice tips. "Don't get hung up on your code". There is a very good reason why this is so difficult to implement and wouldn't recommend it (so long ago now). I ended up changing my UI design and it looks much much better.